# PHP input creating not works fine

Tags: php

so i would like to create input with php like this:

```
 public static function input ( $input_name, $input_type, $input_class, $input_placeholder){
        echo'<input class='.$input_class.' type='.$input_type.' placeholder='.$input_placeholder.' name='.$input_name.' />';
    }
```

But when I'm creating it:

```
$form->input('name', 'text', 'input', 'Input nick');
```

HTML source in page is:

```
<input class="input" placeholder="Input" nick="" name="name" type="text">
```

So, `'Input nick'` should be in placeholder, but it becomes: `placeholder="Input" nick=""`

Comment: Put `"` around property values in function

Answer (score 1):

you need to enclose your values between `""`, like this

```
public static function input ( $input_name, $input_type, $input_class, $input_placeholder){
    echo '<input class="'.$input_class.'" type="'.$input_type.'" placeholder="'.$input_placeholder.'" name="'.$input_name.'" />';
}
```

and `input` is a static function  then you need to call as

```
// Form is the class name
Form::input('name', 'text', 'input', 'Input nick');
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to enclose attributes value under quotes:

**Try This:**

```
 public static function input ( $input_name, $input_type, $input_class, $input_placeholder){
        echo "<input class='$input_class' type='$input_type' placeholder='$input_placeholder' name='$input_name' />";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

$input_placeholder has space between words. It should be inside quotes,

```
function input ( $input_name, $input_type, $input_class, $input_placeholder){
        echo'<input class='.$input_class.' type='.$input_type.' placeholder="'.$input_placeholder.'" name='.$input_name.' />';
    }

    input('name', 'text', 'input', 'Input nick');
```

Comment: this solves the placeholder problem but the other attributes are still not enclosed

Comment: But it will work without quotes at other attributes.

Comment: nope it won't - and the answer "but it will work" doens't indicate a good answer. eg. add multiple class names to this input and it will break again

Comment: Yes, you are right. I checked it in http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php only.